# What is the code for a properly loaded page?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, http-status-code-200

There are error codes when something bad happens to a page but there is also a code when it loads correctly.

What browser code for a page when it loads like it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be HTTP code 200 ("Ok"). NB: This is on http level and has nothing to do with html. It only tells you that the requested content has been accessed correctly.

You can have a look at the RFC for the different HTTP codes. 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually the code returned by the server is 200.

However, the server might also return 304 if the file was not modified since it was last requested.

The details are here: [W3 RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP: 200 is the standard code.  Reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for details on all codes.

In addition to 200, there are others that signal positive response.